# Get domain name without express.js

Tags: node.js

I have a MEAN app which responds to multiple domains. Domains are pointed to same IP and port.

Is there a way to get domain name from client request, without express.js?

So that I can load different database based on request domain name. I tried using `process.domain` and `os.hostname` which does not work on Windows OS (not sure about other OS).

Answer (score 0):

Try picking it out from the header:

```
request.headers.host
```

Comment: could you show your code. Was assuming you are using the `http` native nodejs module.